# "Is it must..." vs "Is it a must..."

Tags: word-usage

I've seen sentences like:

1. Is it must to marry?
2. Is it a must to get married?

I think they both mean the same in this example, but I see some difference in the words.

- What is the difference?
- When to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the word "must" is a verb. Specifically, it's an auxiliary verb, used in sentences like "You must get married!"

Sometimes, the word "must" is used as a noun, meaning an action which is necessary or an object which is needed. This is the way that the word "must" is used in the sentences "Is it a must to get married?" and "For running, good shoes are a must."

However, the word "must" is extremely rarely used as an adjective. So the question "Is it must to marry?" is an error; it should be something like "Must I marry?" or "Is it necessary to marry?"

Comment: while agreeing with your point, one may ask a question, like 'If must can be used as a noun, why can't it be used as an adjective?'

Comment: @RamPillai Well, most verbs can't be used as adjectives, and most nouns can't be used as adjectives, either. So there's no reason to think that "must" might be usable as an adjective.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must-have

Comment: @RamPillai Are you thinking that in the compound "must-have", the word "must" is acting as an adjective? It is not.

Comment: In examples like, 'Mask is a 'must have' for health workers' 'have' stands for a noun and must, an adj.  2) Smoking is a 'must stop'.  3) For aneamic people, iron-compounds are a 'must take'.  These usages may not be common, but articulating a sentence this way, I think, won't violate the grammar rules.

Comment: @RamPillai No, that's definitely not true. In the phrases "must have", "must stop" and "must take", the word "must" is acting as an auxiliary verb followed by an ordinary verb. Then the whole verb phrase is used like a noun.

Comment: How do you define 'a must-have' or 'a must-stop'?  These are noun phrases; at least these function that way.

Comment: @RamPillai Right, but that doesn't mean that "must" is acting as an adjective and "have" and "stop" are acting as nouns. Compare, say, the noun phrase "persona non grata", which obviously doesn't consist of the adjectives "persona" and "non" applied to the noun "grata".

Comment: Taking these constituents separately, I have to agree with you.  PoS is just a broad frame-work and the entire language (here English) can be brought under this. Take a paragraph, and separate the words into PoS, we will find that the leftovers will be just punctuation! It happens due to the functions of words and word-groups - call it phrases or clauses etc. We have heard about noun phrase, adj phrase adverb verb, infinitive phrase etc. each of which has still sub-divisions; so are the case of clauses too.  I should we need to see how a constituent functions. Contd...

Comment: E.g., "He often feared discussing certain things with his wife which, for him, was like walking along a narrow path full of broken glass pieces and rusty thorns where one had to be extremely careful”
// He (pronoun); often (adverb); feared (verb); discussing (verbal noun); certain (adj); things (noun); with (prep.); his (poss. Adj); wife (noun); which (relative Pron.); for (prep); him (pron as obj.); was (aux. verb); like (adj.); walking (verbal noun); along (adv.); a (article/ adj/ det); narrow (adj); path (noun); full(prep); of (prep), (full of – adv. Phrase); broken (adj./participle); ...

Comment: ...glass (noun as adj); pieces (noun); and (conj.); rusty (adj); thorns (noun); where (rel. adv.); one (pron); had (verb); to (prep.); be (verb); extremely (adv.); careful (adj.).      Here, after packing them under each PoS, what is left?

Comment: @RamPillai I suppose sometimes things get a little more complicated than that. Consider: This (determiner) book (noun) is (fin. verb) a (determiner) must (aux. verb) read (inf. verb). We seem to have a determiner followed by a verb phrase, which is normally ungrammatical.